# Binary string comparison/sort vs Dictionary string comparison/sort

Tags: string, sorting, comparison

what is other difference than performance ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on the sorting technique and how big the strings are. The other different other than performance would be the memory usage. Dictionary one will use more memory depending on the size of the string.

Comment: but is there any difference how letter priority is treated or collate?